# How to achieve a silhouette mask in the shader editor?

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, shaders

I'd like to take the silhouette of my object and use it as a mask in the shader editor. Meaning I need a white gradient going inwards from the silhouette my object. All ways I have found online use layer weight/fresnel, but that doesn't help me as it isn't just giving out the silhouette but the contour. Maybe a geo nodes wiz can chime in?

Thank you for any help!